# Context.SaveChanges() doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm a little bit confused.

I have this Code:

```
 using(Test_ASLEntities context = new Test_ASLEntities())
            { 
                List<Belege> kopieren_SQL_List = new List<Belege>();

                kopieren_SQL_List = (from b in context.Beleges
                                    select b).ToList();

                var kopieren_SQL = new Belege
                {
                    Plz = 1000,                   
                    Nachname = "Name",
                    Vorname = "Name",
                };
                kopieren_SQL_List.Add(kopieren_SQL);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

And i dont get it, why it dosn't save the changes in m database?!

The context is from a .edmx datamodel entitites.

Can someone tell me what i did wrong there?
(I just copyed most of the Code out of a other program that i created for quite some time , and there it worked fine. Thats even more confusing)

**Edit: NVM, saw my mistake. Sry :(**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have to use [DbSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset(v=vs.113).aspx) object to signal a new object was added to `EF`
From **MSDN**  what the **Add** method do

*`Adds the given entity to the context underlying the set in the Added state such that it will be inserted into the database when SaveChanges is called.`*

```
 var kopieren_SQL = new Belege
                {
                    Plz = 1000,                   
                    Nachname = "Name",
                    Vorname = "Name",
                };
//EF framework will add a plural S to represents an object collection 
context.Beleges.Add(kopieren_SQL); 
//here  commit your changes to the DB 
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `context.Beleges.Add(kopieren_SQL)` instead of `kopieren_SQL_List.Add(kopieren_SQL)`.

Answer (score 4):

You're not adding your new `Belege` to your datacontext.

Try `context.Beleges.Add(kopieren_SQL)`.